# Spring boot: path param is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've coded this controller method implementation:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/userlogin4download/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET
)
@Override
public void downloadAfterGicar(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    String id
) throws IOException {

    LOG.info("Requested URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
    LOG.info("{id} path param: " + id);

    // other code
}
```

This method is reached. Nevertheless, logs:

```
Requested URI: /userlogin4download/cpd1-dc598036-f615-4200-b685-d24831fb9343
{id} path param: null
```

As you can see `id` path param is `null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ofcourse it is `null` as it isn't a path param because it is missing the `@PathVariable` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `@PathVariable`

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/userlogin4download/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Override
public void downloadAfterGicar(HttpServletRequest request, 
                               HttpServletResponse response,
                               @PathVariable("id") String id) throws IOException {

    LOG.info("Requested URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
    LOG.info("{id} path param: " + id);

    // other code
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was automatically mapped.